# How can I get a variable of a class from an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance

if I have an abstract class and a class that extends it, how can I get variable of the class that extends it to the class that is extended, something like this:

```
abstract class A {
    void getVariable () {
        //get *variable* from class B and print it out
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int variable = 5;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible, unless `variable` is public and static

Comment: You really don't want to do that.

Comment: In my actual code, the variable is private int, but it has a public getter method, can it be done this way?

Comment: only if it's a `public static` method and the variable is also `static`

Comment: you should rather implement getVariable in subclass

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access variable field from child class directly but you can do like this

```
abstract class A {
   abstract int getVariable ();

   void anotherMethod() {

       System.out.println("Variable from child: " + getVariable());
   }
}

class B extends A {
    int variable = 5;

    @Override
    int getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need. Just one question, Itamar Green said in the comments that variable needs to be declared static, does this apply in this case as well?

Comment: No. It does not need to be static! You need to learn more OOP!

Answer (score 0):

Forget about variables: What you might inherit and override is **behaviours** (=methods). Try this:

```
abstract class A {
    protected abstract int getVariable ();
}

class B extends A {
    private int variable = 5;
    protected int getVariable ()
    {
        return variable;
    }
}   

class C extends A {
    protected int getVariable ()
    {
        return 0; // This class might decide not to define its own variable.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`variable` is only known to class `B`. Its superclass `A` has no knowledge of it. If you move `variable` to the superclass `A` and don't mark it `private`, then you can access it from `B`.